# Changing font size and modifying Javascript Show/Hide Toggle

Tags: javascript

I'm a total beginner in Javascript, and I came across this script for a show/hide toggle:

```
<script language="javascript">
function toggle() {
var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
if(ele.style.display == "block") {
ele.style.display = "none";
text.innerHTML = "show";
}
else {
ele.style.display = "block";
text.innerHTML = "hide";
}
} 
</script>
```

I would like to change the font size of the "show" and "hide" in this code. Seems like a really easy task, but I've looked everywhere and can't find an answer.

Also another question, how could I modify the code so that I don't have to copy and paste the whole code and changing `toggle()` to `toggle2()`, `toggle3()` for each separate show/hide toggle on the same page?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can use the `style.fontSize` DOM manipulation method to change the font size in the same manner you use `style.display.`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `element.style.fontSize` to dynamically set the font size of an element.

```js
function toggle() {
  var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
  var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
  if(ele.style.display == "block") {
  ele.style.display = "none";
  text.style.fontSize = "50px";
  text.innerHTML = "show";
  } else {
  ele.style.display = "block";
  text.style.fontSize = "30px";
  text.innerHTML = "hide";
  }
}

document.getElementById("displayText").addEventListener('click', function(){

  toggle();

});
```

```css
#toggleText{
  display:none;
}
#displayText{
  color: #00af00;
  background: #d9d9d9;
  padding: 4px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<p id="displayText">show</p>
<div id="toggleText">
Hidden or naw?
</div>
```

Comment: @NewToJS Yea dont know what I was thinking. :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create toggle2, toggle3, This will make your code redundant. Instead, add a parameter on your toggle to pass the toggleText.

```
<script language="javascript">
function toggle(toggleText) {
var ele = document.getElementById(toggleText);
var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
if(ele.style.display == "block") {
ele.style.display = "none";
text.innerHTML = "show";
}
else {
ele.style.display = "block";
text.innerHTML = "hide";
}
} 
</script>
```

For the font, you can have this on your css.

```
<style>
#displayText {
    font: bold 12px Georgia, serif;
}
</style>
```

Comment: `<a href="javascript:toggle(toggleText);" id="displayText">Show/Hide</a>
<div id="toggleText" style="display: none;">This is Hidden Text</div>`
This is what I have for my html part (in my page), but it doesn't work for multiple toggles (they all link back to the first toggle). Anything wrong with it?

Comment: You should pass the id of the div. Replace the toggleText with the other id's. <a href="javascript:toggle('toggleText');" id="displayText">Show/Hide</a> <div id="toggleText" style="display: none;">This is Hidden Text</div>